# Why/how is my PHP shared host setting argc/argv?

Tags: shared-hosting, php

Until now, I had been checking for the presence of `argc` and `argv` in my script to determine whether requests were coming from the CLI, which worked on several development machines. When placed on a particular shared host, though, the program went into fits. Looking at my routing code, I discovered that the host was setting both `argc` and `argv` for my requests, which mystifies me a bit.

I've since switched to `php_sapi_name` to solve the CLI routing issue, but I wanted to know why and how the shared host was setting those variables in the $_SERVER array. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off asking them as they could give you a specific and probably more accurate answer.

Comment: @MrXexxed They're a shared host. I'm surprised they can answer the phone without getting mixed up :)

Comment: lol yeah I've been there mate, I switched to dedicated so at least I only need to talk to myself when I balls something up.

Comment: I've always tested for CLI mode the opposite way: e.g., `if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))` then you're probably in a CLI context.  Possibly not the best example, but you get the idea.  If you want something a little more robust, you can check multiple such vars -- if any of them are set, you're in a web context.

Comment: Honestly, `php_sapi_name()` might be an even better solution: php.net/php_sapi_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to [this option](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv) (`register_argc_argv`).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe my class help for your script?

[Php command line argument parser](http://arturgspb.ru/read/php-parser-argumentov-komandnoj-stroki-command-line-arguments-parser.html)